# Convert signature into human readable (bouncycastle)

Tags: java, format, bouncycastle, signature, sign

I want to sign a file I read in with `JFileChooser`. But when I print it to the terminal I can only read questonmarks and other not human readable characters. 
My code to sign is:

```
public static void sign() throws Exception{
    byte[] file = fileChooser();

    store = KeyStore.getInstance(storeType);
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(storePath));
    store.load(in, storePassword);
    in.close();

    Key priv = store.getKey("test", storePassword);
    System.out.println(priv.toString() + "priv string");
    X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) store.getCertificate("Subject");
    ContentSigner signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA512withRSA").build((RSAPrivateKey) priv);        

    //Sign Data
    Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA512WithRSA");
    signature.initSign((RSAPrivateKey) priv);
    signature.update(file);

    //Build cms
    CMSTypedData data = new CMSProcessableByteArray(signature.sign()); 
    CMSSignedDataGenerator gen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();

    gen.addSignerInfoGenerator(
            new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(
                    new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().build())
                    .build(signer, cert));

    //Get signed data
    CMSSignedData sigData = gen.generate(data, false);

    byte[] sig = (byte[]) sigData.getSignedContent().getContent();
    sig.toString();
    String content = new String(sig);
    System.out.println("Signed content: " + content + "\n");
}
```

How can I format the signature to human readable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The digital signature is an array of bytes that aren't in a human readable format, so creating a `String` with it won't work as you expect.

If you want to have a "readable" format, you can encode it to Base64, using BouncyCastle's `org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Base64` class (I'm using BouncyCastle 1.56, but previous versions might have similar classes for Base64 conversion):

```java
byte[] base64ByteArray = Base64.encode(sig); // sig is your byte array
String humanReadableString = new String(base64ByteArray); // human readable string
```

To get the original `sig` array back, you must decode the `humanReadableString`:

```java
byte[] originalSigBytes = Base64.decode(humanReadableString.getBytes());
// originalSigBytes will be the same as sig
```

---

**Notes**: if you face any problem related to encoding, you can force the encoding with the `java.nio.charset.Charset` class (in this example, I'm using `UTF-8` but you can use whatever encoding your system uses):

```java
// same thing as above, but using a specific encoding (UTF-8 in this case)
String humanReadableString = new String(base64ByteArray, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
byte[] originalSigBytes = Base64.decode(humanReadableString.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

---

## Alternative

If you prefer, you can also convert to a [Hex-encoded string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) (each byte becomes a string representation of its value in base 16), using BouncyCastle's `org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Hex` class:

```java
byte[] hexEncodedArray = Hex.encode(sig);
String humanReadableString = new String(hexEncodedArray, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

And to get your original `sig` array back:

```java
byte[] originalSigBytes = Hex.decode(humanReadableString.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
// originalSigBytes will be the same as sig
```

---

**One more thing:** when dealing with cryptography stuff, I suggest you to always manipulate the `byte` array instead of converting them to `String`. But if converting to a `String` is mandatory, then use Base64 (or Hex-encoded string).

Comment: By both encoding methods it gives me the Error: The method encode(byte[]) in the type Hex is not applicable for the arguments (CMSSignedData)

Comment: You must use the `byte[] sig` variable, not the `sigData`